# Unable to start debugging. GDB exited unexpectedly with exit code 134 (0x86)

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm trying to use the gdb debugger on macOS BigSur (11.4) without any success. I always get the same error : Unable to start debugging. GDB exited unexpectedly with exit code 134 (0x86), even though I tried to create a certificate and sign it (like this : [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html)), and I tried to enable debugging with the command `csrutil enable --without debug` (like this : https://gist.github.com/gravitylow/fb595186ce6068537a6e9da6d8b5b96d).

I'm using that launch.json file :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "gdb",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/Users/felix/projects/artn_abinitio/build/artn.x",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
       
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm using VsCode : Version: 1.58.0-insider (Universal).

If you have another idea.
Thank you!